# C++ template specialization by type groups combined with basic type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I would like to specialize template by group of types and also by extra definition for some specific simple types. Is it in C++11 and boost 1.60 possible? Following pseudocode illustrates my intention:

```cpp
template <typename T> // Universal definition
struct convert
{  ...  }

template <> /* Definition for integral types like defined by std::type_traits */
struct convert<integral_types>
{  ...  }

template <> /* Definition for floating point types like defined by type_traits */
struct convert<floating_types>
{  ...  }

template <> /* Exception from integral types - specific definition */
struct convert<char>
{  ...  }
```

I think this could be solved by tag dispatcher, but I'm not sure if it's best solution. Another option is `enable_if`, combined with `is_integral` (and similar groups) , but simple `char` type is problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may do something like:

```
template <typename T, typename Enabler = void> // Universal definition
struct convert
{  ...  };

template <typename T> /* Definition for integral types like defined by std::type_traits */
struct convert<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
{  ...  };

template <> /* Exception from integral types - specific definition */
struct convert<char, void>
{  ...  };
```

Comment: note: if you only have c++11 (as per question), `std::enable_if_t` is defined thus: `template<bool B, class T = void> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution without using `std::enable_if_t`:

```
// g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o typetraitstest typetraitstest.C

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T, bool isFloatingPoint, bool isSigned>
struct _Numeric;

template <typename T>
struct _Numeric<T, true, true>
{
  void doit() { std::cout << "FloatingPoint " << sizeof (T) << " byte\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct _Numeric<T, false, true>
{
  void doit() { std::cout << "SignedInt " << sizeof(T) << " byte\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct _Numeric<T, false, false>
{
  void doit() { std::cout << "UnsignedInt " << sizeof(T) << " byte\n";  } 
};

template <>
struct _Numeric<char, false, true>
{
  void doit() { std::cout << "special case char\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Numeric :
  _Numeric<T, std::is_floating_point<T>::value, std::is_signed<T>::value>
{};
  
int
main()
{
  Numeric<float> f;
  Numeric<int32_t> i32;
  Numeric<uint64_t> u64;
  Numeric<char> c;
  
  f.doit();
  i32.doit();
  u64.doit();
  c.doit();
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output (note that `char` seems to be signed):

```
% ./typetraitstest
FloatingPoint 4 byte
SignedInt 4 byte
UnsignedInt 8 byte
special case char
```